# Цвет кнопок на сайте Ipad

Tags: ipad, html, ios, iphone, css

Есть кнопочки на сайте, если зайти с айпада, то цвет кнопочек превращается в градиент от белого к нужному цвету. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 3):

```
.button{
   -webkit-appearance: none;          
}
```